# SpriteKit updating node position causes glitchy animation

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I've been following along [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2007-how-to-make-a-game-like-mega-jump-with-sprite-kit-and-swift-part-1-2) to create a basic platformer game. However, I noticed that updating the `foregroundNode`'s position in the `update` function causes the animation to be far from smooth. Particularly this bit of code (I've only implemented a foreground layer for now):

```
if (avatarNode.position.y - foregroundNode.position.y) > 0 {
    foregroundNode.position = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -(avatarNode.position.y - 200.0))
}
```

Here's a gif of what I see on my device. Notice how the green square kind of shakes vertically as it jumps up. The weird thing is that my fps stays at a constant ~60fps.

[image]

When I comment out the code that updates the foreground node's position, the animation is a lot smoother, but the camera no longer follows the avatar node. What am I doing wrong that's causing this glitchy behavior?

**Edit:** Here is my [source code](https://github.com/kbunarjo/JumperTest).

Comment: How many pixels is the green square moving at a time? Is it 200? Try an SKAction to move it to it's new position so that it's not 'jumping' there.

Comment: @SteveIves yeah it is jumping around 200 points at a time. The score on the top left is determined by the number of points it moves! Lemme try using an skaction! I’ll have to look into how it works first

Comment: OK - you'll probably want an `SKAction moveBy` if I recall correctly.

Comment: @SteveIves instead of adding the impulse, i instead did `avatarNode.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 200, duration: 0.2))`. It did not fix the glitchy issue. Am I missing something?

Comment: Without being able to see all your code, I'm not sure. Did the movement look any different? You could change the duration (of the SKAction moveBy) to something like 1s just to determine if that looks smooth (i.e. 200pts in 0.2s is just too fast) or if perhaps the SKAction is not working or being actioned properly.

Comment: @SteveIves apologies for the late response -- haven't had time to work on this the past couple days. The movement did look slightly different but it was still glitchy. Tried to adjust the duration, but it was still glitchy. I'm assuming this isn't what SpriteKit is supposed to look like, right?

Comment: No - the movement of sprites - even fast movement - doesn’t need much work to get completely smooth. Did you change the duration to 1.0s and did it get really slow? (You said it still wasn’t smooth). Make sure you’re not somehow creating multiple SKActions for the same node all running at the same time.

Comment: @SteveIves yeah I’m creating one skaction in touchesBegan (so I can manually initiate a “jump” cause I got rid of all the platforms to see if reducing the number of nodes would help). Yeah increasing the duration to 1.0s just slows down the animation, but it is still far from smooth. Lemme actually upload my project to GitHub and share it here

Comment: @SteveIves i just added a link to a github repo with my code, if you have time to check it out! I appreciate all your help! :)

Comment: I'll try and have a look...